# Can we install ODBC Simba driver in docker for windows and deploy in Azure App service?

Tags: azure, docker, asp.net-core, odbc, simba

I need to connect to the hive Database using .Net Core so I'm using ODBC Simba driver to perform operations with Hive Data connections. Now the problem I'm facing is I need to install the ODBC driver in Azure App Service (we cannot install custom drivers in Azure App Service) so I'm using docker to image it up and deploy the Docker Image.

If so how can I Install ODBC Simba Driver in docker!

Let me know any possibility. Whether my approach is right?

--Thanks

Comment: I know nothing about Simba, but, if your application already has Simba working, and you are creating a docker image...i mean, the image will already have Simba inside the docker container because docker packs the whole thing, including any components you have used, like this driver thing.

Comment: Do you mean by while restoring the dependencies by running DockerFile, related drivers automatically installed to the image?

Comment: I guess. I mostly work with azure devops and have only the basic container knowledge. but it seems to me, the whole point of using Docker is to pack everything right? If I am wrong and misleading you, I apologise.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks! Jay No worries